Is it possible that visual issues like freezing and ANR not be shown as indicators in Profiler in CPU and MEMORY graphics?
I am using FragmentPagerAdapter (I know its deprecated!) and while swiping between fragments I see some small freezes on the screen (sometimes ANR).
as a parameter I use BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT but after I change this parameter to BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT I do not see those freezes.
I have ran Android Profiler to see if the CPU and MEMORY usage is different between two of them but in both cases CPU and MEMORY graphics looks the same.
The question:
Is it possible that visual issues like freezing and ANR not be shown as indicators in Profiler in CPU and MEMORY graphics?

Sure.  ANR has nothing to do with memory.  And it may nit be CPU bound either-  it just means that a watchdogged function didn't return in time.  If the function is waiting for data (say from a network call) that won't appear pegged on the profiler, because it isn't actively running
